# Django form Validation error not showing up also the form is not authenticating

Tags: python, django, forms, django-authentication, django-crispy-forms

**Outcome needed :** My main aim is to get a guest login that is user adds email address and then django checks for the email in the database if it finds one then error is shown else user is logged in.

**Problem :** In my form when I add an email address then Django adds the email in the database but if I add that email again no error is shown also I am not being logged in Django.

**Version Using:**

- appdirs==1.4.2
- cffi==1.9.1
- cryptography==1.7.2
- Django==1.8.4
- django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
- django-registration-redux==1.4
- enum34==1.1.6
- idna==2.4
- ipaddress==1.0.18
- olefile==0.44
- packaging==16.8
- Pillow==4.0.0
- pyasn1==0.2.3
- pycparser==2.17
- pyOpenSSL==16.2.0
- pyparsing==2.1.10
- requests==2.13.0
- six==1.10.0

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class GuestCheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Verify Email')

    def clean_email2(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        email2 = self.cleaned_data.get("email2")

        if email == email2:
            user_exists = User.objects.filter(email=email).count()
            if user_exists != 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This User already exists. Please login instead.")
            return email2
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please confirm emails are the same")
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin 

# Create your views here.
from orders.forms import GuestCheckoutForm
from orders.models import UserCheckout
from products.models import Variation

from .models import Cart, CartItem

class ItemCountView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            cart_id = self.request.session.get("cart_id")       
            if cart_id == None:
                count = 0
            else:
                cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
                count = cart.items.count()
            request.session["cart_item_count"] = count
            return JsonResponse({"count": count})   
        else:
            raise Http404   



class CartView(SingleObjectMixin, View):
    model = Cart
    template_name = "carts/view.html"

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request.session.set_expiry(0) #5 minutes
        cart_id = self.request.session.get("cart_id")
        if cart_id == None:
            cart = Cart()
            cart.save()
            cart_id = cart.id
            self.request.session["cart_id"] = cart_id
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            cart.user = self.request.user
            cart.save()
        return cart

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cart = self.get_object()
        item_id = request.GET.get("item")
        delete_item = request.GET.get("delete", False)
        item_added = False
        if item_id:
            item_instance = get_object_or_404(Variation, id=item_id)
            qty = request.GET.get("qty", 1)
            try:
                if int(qty) < 1:
                    delete_item = True
            except:
                raise Http404
            cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, item=item_instance)
            if created:
                item_added = True
            if delete_item:
                cart_item.delete()
            else:
                cart_item.quantity = qty
                cart_item.save()
            if not request.is_ajax():
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
                #return cart_item.cart.get_absolute_url()

        if request.is_ajax():
            try:
                total = cart_item.line_item_total
            except:
                total = None
            try:
                subtotal = cart_item.cart.subtotal
            except:
                subtotal = None

            try:
                cart_total = cart_item.cart.total
            except:
                cart_total = None

            try:
                tax_total = cart_item.cart.tax_total
            except:
                tax_total = None    

            try:
                total_items = cart_item.cart.items.count()
            except:
                total_items = 0 

            data = {
                    "deleted": delete_item, 
                    "item_added": item_added,
                    "line_total": total,
                    "subtotal": subtotal,
                    "cart_total": cart_total,
                    "tax_total": tax_total,
                    "total_items": total_items
                    }

            return JsonResponse(data) 


        context = {
            "object": self.get_object()
        }
        template = self.template_name
        return render(request, template, context)

class CheckoutView(FormMixin, DetailView):
        model = Cart
        template_name = "carts/checkout_view.html"
        form_class = GuestCheckoutForm

        def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
                cart_id = self.request.session.get("cart_id")
                if cart_id == None:
                        return redirect("cart")
                cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
                return cart


        def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
                context = super(CheckoutView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
                user_can_continue = False
                user_check_id = self.request.session.get("user_checkout_id")
                if not self.request.user.is_authenticated() or user_check_id == None:# or if request.user.is_guest:
                    context["login_form"] = AuthenticationForm()
                    context["next_url"] = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
                elif self.request.user.is_authenticated() or user_check_id != None:
                    user_can_continue = True
                else:
                    pass
                context["user_can_continue"] = user_can_continue
                context["form"] = self.get_form()
                return context

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                self.object = self.get_object()
                form = self.get_form()
                if form.is_valid():
                    email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
                    user_checkout, created = UserCheckout.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
                    request.session["user_checkout_id"] = user_checkout.id
                    print user_checkout
                    return self.form_valid(form)
                else:
                    return self.form_invalid(form)

        def get_success_url(self):
                return reverse("checkout")
```

**checkout_view.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

{% if not user_can_continue %}
<div class='col-sm-6'>
<p class='lead'>Continue as Guest</p>



<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Continue as Guest' />
</form>


</div>
<div class='col-sm-6'>
<p class='lead'>Login to Continue</p>
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'auth_login' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ login_form|crispy }}

<input type='hidden' name='next' value='{{ next_url }}' />
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Login' />
</form>
<p class='text-center'>

<p>{% trans "Forgot password" %}? <a href="{% url 'auth_password_reset' %}">{% trans "Reset it" %}</a>!</p>
<p>{% trans "Not member" %}? <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">{% trans "Register" %}</a>!</p>
</p>

</div>

{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class UserCheckout(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True) #not required
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True) #--> required


    def __unicode__(self): #def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

As such I am getting no error but the problems stated above are occurring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clean_*` methods in django should [**always return the `value`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

```
def clean_email2(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    email2 = self.cleaned_data.get("email2")

    if email == email2:
        # Query your UserCheckout model. Not the auth one!
        if UserCheckout.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This User already exists. Please login instead.")
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please confirm emails are the same")
    return email2
```

Comment: ...except an exception is raised.

Comment: That solved one problem of custom Validation error but if the email dont exist in db then it is not logging me as a new user

Comment: Do you have any other validations that's preventing user to login?

Comment: Would you mind to add a `print('error')` statement under the `if ...exists():` and one under the `else` clause and see if any of them gets printed?

Comment: In my console no error got printed after adding print('error')

Comment: So this means that the `clean_email2` method worked. Maybe the problem is located somewhere else...?

Comment: I think I got the answer first I need to login as the super user then only it allow me to login as guest . But thanks for answering my doubts

Comment: No problem. Glad I could contribute to your goals!